# Set size of individual UICollectionView cell

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

Is there a way to change the size of the first cell only in a `UICollectionView` and assign the other cells a different size?

I've tried doing something like this but it doesn't work:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if (indexPath == 0){
        return CGSize(200, height: 200)
    } else {
        return CGSize(300, height: 300)
    }
}
```

Comment: How does "it doesn't work" manifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndexPath` consists of two properties, `item` and `section`, in a collection view.

You can't check if `indexPath == 0` because `0` is not an index path.

Replace your `if` statement with the following:

```
if indexPath == IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0) {
```

This will give you the first item in the first section of the collection view.

Comment: Or you can do: `if indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.item == 0 {`